# duration and period for observation settings

Tags: differences

I have a question on which to use "duration" or "period".
I would like to use the word for settings of some observations using a sensor.

I searched on the Internet and found the following.
http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic3594.html

> Duration means the length of time something lasts: the duration of the flight - the duration of the war - the duration of the parliament. Period refers to a particular time in history/the past as in the classical period in music the romantic period in poetry.

From the above, the "period" seems the thing of the past. The "duration" seems the word to use.

On the other hand, on page 23 of the following, I found "Period" for "Schedule > Measurement speed".

http://rbr-global.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/RUG-LL-0000703rev7.pdf

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/), I found

> Period 6a: a portion of time determined by some recurring phenomenon
>
> Duration 2: the time during which something exists or lasts

Question: Which shall I use for the settings of observations by a sensor?

Comment: What is it going to be used for? A variable name?

Comment: @marcellothearcane It will be written as document and be shown in setting dialog.

Comment: "the *period* seems the thing of the past" - No.

Comment: Both work. If the same amount time is applicable for repeated observations, then *period* is better; OTOH, *duration* (of observation) is fine in **all** cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that either "duration" or "period" could reasonably be used for your purpose, but in this technical context I would suggest that "duration" has the edge, and also the least scope for ambiguity.

I disagree with the quote you found saying that "period" is always about historical eras. Period does have a number of specialised meanings, and that is indeed a common one of them, but by no means the only one. Specialised uses of "period" include:

- Historical eras, such as the Medieval period, or the Tudor Period in British history.
- In the geological timescale, Eons are divided into Eras, which in turn are subdivided into Periods (such as the Jurassic Period and Cambrian Period). Periods are further divided into Epochs, and those into Ages.
- In astronomy, the period of a celestial body or satellite is the time it takes to perform one full rotation.
- To physiologists, the period of the blood is the time it takes to make one full circulation of the body.
- In physics, a period is the length of one cycle of any oscillatory or cyclic phenomenon, such as sine waves, light waves, sound waves, etc.
- In mathematics, a periodic function is a function that returns the same value at regular intervals.
- In music, a period is a recurring structure typically comprising two musical phrases.

You will notice from the last five of these examples that "period" very often refers to durations that are cyclical. (This is also how the female menstrual cycle comes to be known as a period.) Period has yet another meaning to Americans and Canadians, of course, being the sentence-terminating punctuation known to Brits as a full stop.

The word "duration" comes with rather less baggage. It doesn't have all the specialised meanings of "period" across different disciplines, and nor does it imply cyclicity as "period" often does. Don't get me wrong: I think both words would be absolutely suitable for your proposed use, but if I had to pick one as preferable for clarity, I would go with "duration".

For the sake of completeness, alternative words and phrases meaning "length of time" include term, spell, and timespan (or simply span, as in lifespan). The first two of these are probably less suited to your purpose, but timespan may work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed reply. The ample examples of period helps me to understand more. Also other than the "term" and "time span", I did not know the "spell" is also used as the meaning of "length of time". I appreciate also about the comment that which words are suitable and which are not for the purpose.

Comment: You're welcome. Usually "spell" is not used for specific lengths of time; it is typically more vague. "He had a spell in prison" means the same as "he was in prison for a while". It is also used in the weather expression "sunny spells", which means intermittent periods of sunshine in between cloudy periods.